# how to debug /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d scripts

Tags: bash, scripts, network-manager

The [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/NetworkManager.8.html) says:

> ```
>    NetworkManager will execute scripts in the /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d directory
> ```

It also says:

> ```
>    The environment contains more information about the interface and the connection. The
>    following variables are available for the use in the dispatcher scripts:
>
>    NM_DISPATCHER_ACTION
>        The dispatcher action like "up" or "dhcp4-change", identical to the first command line
>        argument. Since NetworkManager 1.12.0.
>
>        ......
> ```

My question is, how can I test or debug these scripts when the environment variables are only available inside this context.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465273/how-to-debug-the-networkmanager-dispatcher-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly debugging but you can see stdout in

```
systemctl status NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
```

Which is what I needed when I got to this post